# How to automate this popup in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, popup, alerts

[image]

How to automate this popup in Selenium (Java). Please help me.

Comment: How is going? If my answer was helpful -- please check a tick near my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try on the below code:

```
driver.get("http://username:password@your_link");
```

where username and password -- your creds for authentication popup, your_link -- link to the site, where is raised authentication popup.

Comment: @bhargavporapu, you are welcome!